# Pjax back button not working when URL updated with Parameters

Tags: jquery, pjax

When I do a manual update the url with some parameters like ?page=2 it won't be recognized by pjax:

```
window.history.replaceState(null,document.title,"?page=2");
```

I tried using pjax as well

```
$.pjax({url: "?page=2", container: (container || '#null'), replace: true, dontRequest: true})
```

(Note I added the dontRequest parameter so I could do a "fake" pjax call that wouldn't actually fire the .ajax but still update the url, with no success)

To replicate this on a live site:

1. Go to http://2u.fm (click out of the modal)
2. Scroll down until ?p=2 is added
3. Click Popular
4. Press back in your browser

Note nothing happens... now press back again and you'll see it works.  This is because I update the URL with ?p=2 using replaceState.  How would I make this work so that it recognizes these ? params... I tried customizing pjax with no success.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but I will give an answer for anyone that happens to come around here as I did.

Pjax doesn't work perfectly when you use pushState or replaceState manually on the page. When it encounters such a state, it simply does nothing. So when you press back/forward buttons to such a page, pjax:popstate event doesn't fire and nothing happens.

A workaround would be to use $.pjax.state as the state object argument of pushState and replaceState

```
history.pushState($.pjax.state, null, href)
```

and

```
history.replaceState($.pjax.state, null, href)
```

There are some issues in github regarding this problem:
[issue/381](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax/issues/381) , [issue/495](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax/issues/495)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that PJAX only adds path, not full url to state. This is why you are getting this problem.

If you are using Rails, then definitely try Wiselinks https://github.com/igor-alexandrov/wiselinks. It is a a Swiss Army knife for browser state management. Here are some details: http://igor-alexandrov.github.io/blog/2013/07/11/the-way-to-wiselinks-1-dot-0/.

Wiselinks handles this and many other situations better.